# Stylesheet control for QComboBox tick?

Tags: qt4

I have a nice stylesheet for a QComboBox but I can't find how to style the tick.

The tick is a graphic that appears next to the currently selected item. There are two problems: 1. When the mouse is on the currently selected item, the `selection-background-color` is applied to the item but not the tick. 2. When another item is highlighted the tick is drawn disabled with an ugly stipple effect.

I guess it's somewhere under `QComboBox::on` but I don't know what it is.

Comment: What platform are you having problems on? And how are you specifying the stylesheet for the QComboBox, e.g. QML, Designer, in-code?

Comment: C++, Mac, in code stylesheet: `qApp->setStyleSheet(my_styles_string)`.

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac to help with this. Have you tried looking at the Qt source code? In the past, when I've got stuck with some Qt behaviour, I've often looked at the Qt source for the relevant platform, and found that reading it helps me understand. For example, you could try to work out whether Qt actually uses stylesheet info when drawing the ticks on QComboBoxes - and if so, what names you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important control appears to be `QComboBox::checked`. Make sure to set `color` and `background-color`. Background colour cannot be a gradient. If background colour is set to the same as the rule for `QComboBox QAbstractItemView` then the chess board effect (stippling) can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the general style using:

```
#include <QCleanlooksStyle>

QCleanlooksStyle cleanLook;
QComboBox * combo = new QComboBox;
combo->setStyle(&cleanLook);
```

then the check marks aren't shown at all.